# Alamofire unable disable caching

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlcache

I can not get Alamofire or iOS to stop caching:

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
```

or

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

I need to disable it for all requests?

Also tried:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.urlCache = nil
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

This give this error:

```
Auth request failed with error:
 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8080/slow/file.json, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8080/slow/file.json}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working:

```
URLCache.shared = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
```

And then just `Alamofire.request`

Answer (score 1):

To disable you urlCache you have to create custom Alamofire `Manager`
with `nil` urlCache.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.urlCache = nil
let manager = Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

More information you can find in [Apple Documenation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1410148-urlcache)

> To disable caching, set this property to nil.

Comment: Manager == SessionManager? Thanks; Setting SessionManager does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In **Alamofire 5.0** you should create an instance of `ResponseCacher` and set its caching behavior to `.doNotCache` and then inject it to a new `Session` and use only that session:

```
static let mySession = Session(cachedResponseHandler: ResponseCacher(behavior: .doNotCache))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()` before each Alamofire request to stop caching

Comment: FYI it doesn't work, Alamofire is using its own mechanism

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alter the properties of a `URLSessionConfiguration` that has already been used to initialize a `URLSession`, which is what your code sample is doing. Like [k8mil said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568688/272952), you should create your own Alamofire `SessionManager` with the cache disabled if you want this behavior.